# python substring (slicing) compare not always working

Tags: python-3.x

```
`list1 = ["Arizona","Atlanta","Baltimore","Buffalo","Carolina","Chicago",
"Cincinnati","Cleveland","Dallas","Denver","Detroit","Green Bay","Houston",
"Indianapolis","Jacksonville","Kansas City","L.A. Chargers","L.A. Rams",
    "Miami","Minnesota","New England","New Orleans","NY Giants","NY Jets",
    "Oakland","Philadelphia","Pittsburgh","San Francisco","Seattle",
    "Tampa Bay","Tennessee","Washington"]
a = "New Orleans at Oakland"
k = a.find("at")
print (k)
for n in range(0,31):
#    b = list1[n]
#    print(b[0:k-1]+"  "+a[0:k-1])
    idx = a.find(list1[n], 0, k-1)
    if idx > 0:
        print(n)
        break
print ("awa team at index" + str(n+1))
for n in range(0,31):
    idx = a.find(list1[n], k+2, len(a))
    if idx > 0:
       print(n)
       break
print ("hom team at index" + str(n+1))`
```

I just started python 2 days ago and I cannot get this to work completely. The program finds the team in the second for loop correctly, but doesn't find the team in the first for loop. I put in the statements that are commented out to see if the strings were somehow truncated, but they are correct. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to brute force the search. Python has methods that accomplish what you need.

```
list1 = ["Arizona", "Atlanta", "Baltimore", "Buffalo", "Carolina", "Chicago",
"Cincinnati", "Cleveland", "Dallas", "Denver", "Detroit", "Green Bay", "Houston",
"Indianapolis", "Jacksonville", "Kansas City", "L.A. Chargers", "L.A. Rams",
"Miami", "Minnesota", "New England", "New Orleans", "NY Giants", "NY Jets",
"Oakland", "Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", "San Francisco", "Seattle",
"Tampa Bay", "Tennessee", "Washington"]

a = "New Orleans at Oakland"

# Create a list of the teams involved in the game
teams = a.split(" at ")

# Iterate through the teams involved in the game
for team in teams:
    # The index() method returns the lowest index in list that obj appears
    index = list1.index(team)
    # If the the team was found then index is valid
    if index:
        print(index)
        print(list1[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to have the index, you can use the .index() you do not have to "loop"

Example code:

```
list1 = ["Arizona","Atlanta","Baltimore","Buffalo","Carolina","Chicago",
"Cincinnati","Cleveland","Dallas","Denver","Detroit","Green Bay","Houston",
"Indianapolis","Jacksonville","Kansas City","L.A. Chargers","L.A. Rams",
    "Miami","Minnesota","New England","New Orleans","NY Giants","NY Jets",
    "Oakland","Philadelphia","Pittsburgh","San Francisco","Seattle",
    "Tampa Bay","Tennessee","Washington"]

a = "New Orleans at Oakland"

a = a.split(' at ')

idx_home_team = list1.index(a[0])
idx_away_team = list1.index(a[1])

print(idx_home_team, idx_away_team)
```